# How can I bind the visibility of a XAML Component to a model property?

Tags: winui-3, winui

I want to bind the visibility of

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Time}" />
```

to a variable.

I tried to bind it to Visibility enum and google the problem. Found no solution for winui 3.

Comment: You can create a "Visibility" property or `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Visibility` type on your ViewModel object and bind it like this: `<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Time}" Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.Visibility, Mode=TwoWay}" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Simon Mourier mentioned in a comment, you can just bind to a "Visibility" property in your *ViewModel*:

```cs
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Visibility timeVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Note:

I'm using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) NuGet package to implement the *ViewModel*.

- [ObservableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject)
- [ObservableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty)

```xml
<TextBlock
    Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Time}"
    Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.TimeVisibility, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Or, if you want to avoid "UI" related code in your *ViewModel*, you can bind the `TextBlock`'s `Visibility` to a `bool` and use a `ValueConverter` like this:

```cs
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string time = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isTimeVisible = false;
}
```

```cs
public class TrueToVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is bool boolValue && boolValue is true
            ? Visibility.Visible
            : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<TextBlock
    Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Time}"
    Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsTimeVisible, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisibleConverter}}" />
```